# String indices must be integers Giphy

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, giphy

I'm trying to get url from object data, but it isn't right. This program has stopped on line 4. Code is under.

My code:

```
    import requests

    gifs = str(requests.get("https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random? 
    api_key=APIKEY"))
    dump = json.dumps(gifs)
    json.loads(dump['data']['url'])
```

Comment: Assuming you use the standard Python [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) function, it returns a *string* and not any kind of JSON "object" or dictionary.

Comment: Also, please don't put "tags" in the title, the actual tags are enough.

Comment: Make sure you post enough code that we can copy and run by ourselves. (Hint: your code does not.)

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not clear enough. You expect to read a json and select a field that brings you something?
I recommend you check this section of [requests quickstart guide](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) this i suspect you want to read the data to json and extract from some fields.
Maybe something like this might help:

```
r = requests.get('http://whatever.com')  
url = r.json()['url']
```